# Solution architecture for data transfer from SQL Server database to external API and back

Tags: azure, datagrid, azure-functions

I am looking for a proper solution architecture for a data transfer scenario from SQL Server to an external API and then from the API back to SQL Server. We are thinking of using Azure technologies.

We have a database hosted on an Azure VM. When the value of the author of the book table changes, we would like to get all the data for that book from related table and transfer it an external API. the quantity of the rows to be transferred (the select-join) is huge so it takes a long time to execute the select-join query, After this data is read it is transformed and then it is sent to an external API (over which we have no control) The transfer of the data to the API could take up to an hour. After the data is written into this API, we read some reports from this API and write these reports back into the original database.
We must repeat this process more than 50 per day.

We are thinking of using Logic app to detect the trigger from SQL Server (as it is hosted in Azure VMs) publish this even to an Azure Data grid and then use Azure Durable functions to handle the Read SQL data-Transform it- and Send to the external API.

Does this make sense? Does anybody have any better ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, Logic App SQL connector can't detect when a particular row changes, it will perform a select (which you'll provide), and then it will check for changes every X interval (you'll specify).

In other words, SQL Database doesn't offer a change feed like CosmosDB where you can subscribe to events and trigger an Azure Function.

Things you can do:

1-Add a Trigger on SQL after insert / update which will insert the new/changed row into a separated table, and then you can use Logic App / Azure Functions to query this table and retrieve data.

2-Migrate to Cosmos DB and use the change feed + Azure Functions

3-Change your code to after insert into SQL Database, also add a message with the Identifier for the row you're about to insert / update, then add it to a Queue, which will be consumed by Azure Function.